# How to start an application using Android ADB tools

Tags: android, adb

How do I send an intent using Android's ADB tools?

Comment: stop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117095/stopping-an-android-app-from-console

Comment: Get ActivityName: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37959688

Answer (score 755, accepted):

```
adb shell
am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

Or you can use this directly:

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

You can also specify actions to be filter by your intent-filters:

```
am start -a com.example.ACTION_NAME -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

Comment: Thank you very much , i've made it shell function in ~/.bash_profile to be much faster  `function androidrun(){ ant clean debug
adb shell am start -n $1/$1.MainActivity
}` and its usage `androidrun com.example.test`

Comment: `adb shell am` will give you a list of other options to pass to the `am` command. You can find out more at https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#am

Comment: @shurane How can I find -a option?

Comment: @ericyoung I don't have access to a device offhand, but you can try just running `adb shell am`, which will list some more detailed help compared to the documentation.

Comment: is is possible to run the default activity, instead of being so specific to which activity i intend it should start?

Comment: AFAIK, you can omit part of the command like in Joilnen answer

Comment: I had problems finding the application and activity. I used this pipe line `adb logcat  | grep --line-buffered  ActivityManager | grep --line-buffered` to list all applications that were displayed.

Comment: Can you add an example of how to launch it with a deep link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5494891/236465 shows how to use `cmd` and how to obtain the Activity name knowing the package

Comment: This answer works on Oculus Go (as there is no way on its UI to run normal android apps) but it displays a non-VR view of the app. However, if your install and run your app through visual studio, you see the VR view of your app!

Comment: If you have a dollar sign in an activity name, use 3 backslashes to escape it, e.g.  
`adb shell "am start -a android.settings.SYNC_SETTINGS -n com.android.settings/.Settings\\\$AccountDashboardActivity"`

Comment: `com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName`, can be shortened/reduced to, `com.package.name/.ActivityName`

Answer (score 420):

It's possible to run an application specifying the package name only using the **monkey** tool by follow this pattern:

```
adb shell monkey -p your.app.package.name -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

The command is used to run the app using the monkey tool which generates random input for the application. The last part of the command is an integer which specifies the number of generated random input for the app. In this case the number is 1, which in fact is used to launch the app (icon click).

Comment: Launcher is default. You can simplify to `adb shell monkey -p your.app.package.name 1`

Comment: Is it possible to use the APK file name, instead of the package name? Suppose I have an APK file, and I want to be able to install&run it, is it possible?

Comment: What if I get an error: **no activities found to run.  aborting**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky if no activities found, it's a Service app and has no Activity at all.

Comment: `--pct-syskeys 0` is required for devboards: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46935109/895245

Comment: @WSS im sorry but i think you're wrong. An visible APP has main activity at least. If you don't have activity nothing will happen except the case that you init a service at launch, ie notification app. Take a read: https://www.quora.com/Can-an-Android-app-be-made-without-an-activity. Regards.

Comment: @erm3nda sorry, I was wrong and that app worked. Since the app was open source I imported its project, but it has some problems and it caused it to fail.

Comment: @WSS no worries :)

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky if it is a service use `adb shell am startservice com.some.package.name/.YourServiceSubClassName` see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18703083/211292

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. In particular, Androiderson's comment.

Comment: @androiddeveloper You can use the android tools to get the android package name and then launch that. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289149/read-the-package-name-of-an-android-apk

Comment: I found this to be the most useful technique because it only requires the package name and not the name of the launcher activity.

Comment: ty, best answer I have got.

Comment: This helps me to launch gmail app. Thanks!
To launch gmail app using adb shell
 `adb shell monkey -p com.google.android.gm -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1`

Comment: It works, but has problems: 1) will launch random activity every time, 2) cannot add deeplink string. If you get `** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.` check that you didn't unistall an app.

Answer (score 138):

Or, you could use this:

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/.ActivityName
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without specifying the activity name, so that the default main activity will start?

Comment: @androiddeveloper See the *monkey* command below from *depodefi*: no need to specify activity name!

Comment: @DanielBeauyat Nice. it works even on a device. Here's the link to the post, BTW: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25398877/878126

Comment: It should be noted that if you use an `applicationIdSuffix` such as `.debug` for your debug builds, you have to use the fully qualified activity name: `adb shell am start -n com.package.name.debug/com.package.name.ActivityName`. The suffix only applies to the application id, not the package name of the java classes.

Comment: What if I don't know the **ActivityName**?

Comment: Run    ~/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/20.0.0/aapt dump badging yourapp.apk   , which will list the following entry: launchable-activity: name='com.company.android.package.YourLaunchableActivity'

Comment: `monkey -p com.package.name 1` via `adb shell`

Answer (score 65):

Linux and Mac users can also create a script to run an [APK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file with something like the following:

Create a file named "adb-run.sh" with these three lines:

```
pkg=$(aapt dump badging $1|awk -F" " '/package/ {print $2}'|awk -F"'" '/name=/ {print $2}')
act=$(aapt dump badging $1|awk -F" " '/launchable-activity/ {print $2}'|awk -F"'" '/name=/ {print $2}')
adb shell am start -n $pkg/$act
```

Then "chmod +x adb-run.sh" to make it executable.

Now you can simply:

```
adb-run.sh myapp.apk
```

The benefit here is that you don't need to know the package name or launchable activity name. Similarly, you can create "adb-uninstall.sh myapp.apk"

Note: This requires that you have [Android Asset Packaging Tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2) (`aapt`) in your path. You can find it under the new build tools folder in the SDK.

Comment: for windows you can try with cygwin (untested)

Comment: Your post made me look up AWK. I went ahead and re-created your script. http://pastebin.com/X7X1SsFa

Comment: This is fabulous. Why this isn't a standard adb command we'll never know.

Comment: You won't need to have aapt in your path (as long as "android" is) if you set the PATH in the adb-run.sh script, like this:
    PATH=$(dirname $(which android))/../build-tools/20.0.0:$PATH

Comment: @dljava why does this  not work on https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amaze.filemanager ?

Comment: This answer is a real Good asset. I substituted aapt with : $HOME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/<version>/aapt

Comment: Note that there might be more than one launchable activity in one apk (I think) -- besides it might be better to run aapt only once...

Answer (score 40):

Step 1: First get all the package names of the apps installed in your device, by using:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

Step 2: You will get all the package names. **Copy** the one you want to start using [ADB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_Debug_Bridge_(ADB)).

Step 3: Add your desired package name in the below command.

```
adb shell monkey -p 'your package name' -v 500
```

For example,

```
adb shell monkey -p com.estrongs.android.pop -v 500
```

to start the Es explorer.

Comment: This will launch your application and send 500 pseudo-random events to it. So use '1' to replace '500' is better.

Comment: What is "Es explorer"? For example, can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50225901/edit) a reference to it? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 33):

The shortest command yet is the following:

```
adb shell monkey -p your.app.package.name 1
```

This will launch the default activity for the package that is in the launcher.

*Thanks to [Androiderson for the tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools/14910484#comment54583265_25398877)*.

Comment: Bam! Works great, even on Android 4.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Also, I want to mention one more thing.

When you start an application from `adb shell am`, ***it automatically adds FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag*** which makes behavior change. See the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/483f3b06ea84440a082e21b68ec2c2e54046f5a6/cmds/am/src/com/android/commands/am/Am.java#433).

For example, if you launch a Play Store activity from `adb shell am`, pressing the '*Back*' button (hardware back button) wouldn't take you back to your app. Instead, it would take you to the previous Play Store activity if there was some (if there was not a Play store task, then it would take you back to your app). [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) says:

> if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in

This caused me to spend a few hours to find out what went wrong.

So, keep in mind that `adb shell am` ***add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag***.

Comment: Also, worth mentioning that that there is no way to clear said flag, which is annoying

Comment: would it help to supply the flag (-f) FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK?

Comment: What do you mean by *"take you your app"* (seems incomprehensible. ***Two*** instances)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23864073/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 18):

We can as well start an application by knowing the application type and feeding it with data:

```
adb shell am start -d "file:///sdcard/sample.3gp" -t "video/3gp" -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

This command displays available *video players to play a *sample.3gp* file.

Answer (score 17):

You can find your app package name by the below command:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

The above command returns a package list of all apps. Example:

```
org.linphone.debug
.
.
com.android.email
```

Now I want to start app *[linphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linphone)* by using the below command and this worked for me:

```
adb shell am start org.linphone.debug
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't work on Android 4.4. 1. the package names are all prefixed with `package:` (e.g. `package:com.cnn.mobile.android.phone`). 2. When trying to launch (with or without the `package:` prefix), I get `Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pkg=com.cnn.mobile.android.phone }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.cnn.mobile.android.phone }`.

Answer (score 15):

Open file *~/.bash_profile*, and add these Bash functions to the end of the file

```
function androidinstall(){
   adb install -r ./bin/$1.apk
}

function androidrun(){
   ant clean debug
   adb shell am start -n $1/$1.$2
}
```

Then open the Android project folder:

```
androidinstall app-debug && androidrun com.example.app MainActivity
```

Comment: Can you explain what `app-debug` does?

Comment: @TrevorSenior app-debug is the title of the apk file , usually in debug mode the generated apk file is titled "APPLICATION NAME-debug.apk"

Answer (score 11):

**`monkey --pct-syskeys 0` for development boards**

This argument is needed for development boards without keys/display:

```
adb shell monkey --pct-syskeys 0 -p com.cirosantilli.android_cheat.textviewbold 1
```

Without it, the app won't open, and you will get an error message like:

```
SYS_KEYS has no physical keys but with factor 2.0%
```

It was tested on HiKey960, Android O AOSP.

Learned from: *[this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ARM-software/lisa/pull/408)*

Also asked at: *[How to use the monkey command with an Android system that doesn't have physical keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860475/monkey-test-if-the-android-system-doesnt-has-physical-keys-what-are-the-param/46935037#46935037)*

Answer (score 9):

Use:

`adb shell am start -n '<appPackageName>/<appActitivityName>'`

To get `<appPackageName>` run :

`adb shell pm list packages`

To get `<appActitivityName>` lunch app and run

`adb shell dumpsys window | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'`

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
adb shell am start -n '<appPackageName>/.<appActitivityName>
```

Example:

```
adb shell am start -n 'com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiStatusTest'
```

You can use the APK-INFO application to know the list of app activities with respect to each app package.

Comment: your example codes don't show usage of ` APK-INFO`

Comment: What is "APK-INFO"? For example, can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50225901/edit) a reference to it? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 3):

```sh
adb shell am start -n com.app.package.name/com.java.package.name.ActivityName
```

Example

```sh
adb shell am start -n com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.search.core.google.GoogleSearch
```

If the Java package is the same, then it can be shortened:

```
adb shell am start -n com.example.package/.subpackage.ActivityName
```

Answer (score 2):

The right way would be to use `cmd package resolve-activity` to find the startup activity before launching, so you can launch with

`am start $(cmd package resolve-activity --brief com.package.name | tail -n 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for opening an Android photo app and with the specific image file to open as a parameter.

```
adb shell am start -n com.google.android.apps.photos/.home.HomeActivity -d file:///mnt/user/0/primary/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot.png
```

It will work on latest version of Android. No pop up will come to select an application to open as you are giving the specific app to which you want to open your image with.

Comment: I have a player app, which is able to stream a video from url, how can i pass this url as a parameter and stream from that url? suppose a url from youtube?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to open a Flutter app, you can use this command:

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
```

Replace `com.package.name` with your package name. You find your package in your `app/build.gradle` at `applicationId`.

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee support for Android TV as well as non-Android TV apps:

```
adb shell "monkey -p com.package.name -c android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER 1 || monkey -p com.package.name -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1"
```