# How to run a specific Android app using Terminal?

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator, terminal, adb

I installed Eclipse and Android SDK already. Everything is running fine.

I want to install an .apk file so I follow the instruction already. But the problem is, when I start the emulator, it doesn't run my app automatically.

Is there a command in the terminal that allow me to run the specific app that I ask for it?

Comment: do you a nice wait to stop the activity too ? kill $(pidof ...) ?

Answer (score 75):

Use the `cmd activity start-activity` (or the alternative `am start`) command, which is a command-line interface to the [ActivityManager](http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html). Use `am` to start activities as shown in this help:

```
$ adb shell am
usage: am [start|instrument]
       am start [-a <ACTION>] [-d <DATA_URI>] [-t <MIME_TYPE>]
                [-c <CATEGORY> [-c <CATEGORY>] ...]
                [-e <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_VALUE> [-e <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_VALUE> ...]
                [-n <COMPONENT>] [-D] [<URI>]
       ...
```

For example, to start the **Contacts** application, and supposing you know only the package name but not the `Activity`, you can use

```
$ pkg=com.google.android.contacts
$ comp=$(adb shell cmd package resolve-activity --brief -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER $pkg | tail -1)
$ adb shell cmd activity start-activity $comp
```

or the alternative

```
$ adb shell am start -n $comp
```

See also http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/instrumentation_testing.html (may be a copy of obsolete url : http://source.android.com/porting/instrumentation_testing.html ) for other details.

To terminate the application you can use

```
$ adb shell am kill com.google.android.contacts
```

or the more drastic

```
$ adb shell am force-stop com.google.android.contacts
```

Comment: Hi dtmilano. I am trying activity manager also, but I don't know the component of an application. Would you mind explaining further?

Comment: For example: I have a compiled file in /opt/sdk/example.apk   After I install it in, how can I make it run in commandline?

Comment: so.. how do you stop? I've tried adb stop...

Comment: Is there a way to launch an application and wait until it stops?

Comment: Do you mean when Activity is stopped? Add some log message in `onStop()` and then search `logcat` until you find the message.

Comment: @Diego: Would be great if you could update this answer and include some details/example on how to use the other command line switches like: `-e, -t, -d` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately getting an error: 
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.contacts/.ContactsActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.google.android.contacts/com.google.android.contacts.ContactsActivity} does not exist.

Comment: You forgot to mention that it is not trivial to find the main Activity of a package/app from the command line.

Comment: @RobertSiemer updated

Answer (score 7):

I keep [this build-and-run script](https://gist.github.com/31c127901c4b63e96e1d) handy, whenever I am working from command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PACKAGE=com.example.demo
ACTIVITY=.MainActivity
APK_LOCATION=app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
echo "Package: $PACKAGE"

echo "Building the project with tasks: $TASKS"
./gradlew $TASKS

echo "Uninstalling $PACKAGE"
adb uninstall $PACKAGE

echo "Installing $APK_LOCATION"
adb install $APK_LOCATION

echo "Starting $ACTIVITY"
adb shell am start -n $PACKAGE/$ACTIVITY
```

Comment: When I run this command I'm getting an error saying **Error: Activity class {com.example.demo/com.example.demo.MainActivity} does not exist.**. You know how to solve this? It also says Error type 3

Comment: @Ezio Please change line 2 in script to point to your main activity. In my case it is: MainActivity.java in root of the package => com.example.demo.MainActivity. This will be something different for you. Also you need to update the package name (com.example.demo) at line 1 to your app's package name.

Comment: I know about that Shubham, I made all the changes that you said but still getting the error. But now I used **adb shell monkey -p com.mypackage.name -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1** and it worked. I wrote an answer in case anyone else is facing similar issues

Answer (score 6):

You can Start the android Service by this command.

> adb shell am startservice  -n packageName/.ServiceClass

Comment: i appreciate you answer,but please describe your answer in some details not in only two lines for users help.

Answer (score 5):

I used all the above answers and it was giving me errors so I tried

`adb shell monkey -p com.yourpackage.name -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1`

and it worked. One advantage is you dont have to specify your launcher activity if you use this command.

Comment: I could only get it with this monkey command thanks. The others were giving me permission errors.

Comment: Is the monkey command on all Android devices? I have blind code execution on an embedded Android device, don't know what commands it has and what commands it doesn't have.

Comment: the monkey command is an adb command, it does not depend on the device, rather it is present in your development machine.