# App intents in Android

Tags: android

I need to launch an app from the command line with

```
am start com.project.app
```

but it says unable to resolve intent.

I understand that I need to supply the intent, but I don't know what the intent is. I just want to start the app. Is there any way I can list the intents that the app has, find out what the intent was for an app already started, or find out the intent from a shortcut on the home screen?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494764/how-to-run-a-specific-android-app-using-terminal. This might help you.

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613889/how-to-start-an-android-application-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

To start an activity of any package, you need to provide the component name of that package.
It is something like /. or defined in the AndroidManifest.xml

for example, Package name: com.me.test and Activity name is com.me.test.app.TestActivity. Then you need to write

```
am start -n com.me.test/.app.TestActivity
```

Comment: I know, but I don't know what the activity name is.