# ADB command to toggle camera modes in android device

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to figure out what is the command to load the camera app in different modes like following:

1. Toggle between camera and video cam corder mode
2. Toggle between front and back camera

I have used the following command to launch the camera applicaiton

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.CameraLauncher
```

which does launch the camera app successfully but I do no know how to toggle modes. Is there any wiki on all the different commands of ADB? the ADB documentation does not seem to talk about this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass an Extra with an integer value using the --ei flag to the `am start` command

Front Camera

```
adb shell am start -a android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE --ei android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING 1
```

Back Camera

```
adb shell am start -a android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE --ei android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. However if it works for front and back camera options. why it does nto work when I try to trun flash off by android.intent.extras.FLASH_MODE_OFF 1? I have a similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667094/intent-does-not-set-the-camera-parameters    can you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following though:

```
Intent action = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");  
        action.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
```

You can use adb command "am start" . Please read following: [How to run a specific Android app using Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494764/how-to-run-a-specific-android-app-using-terminal)

Comment: Untrue - if you can do this with a programmatic Intent, you can send that same Intent using ADB commands - you were on the right track in your question, you just need to fill in the fields.

Comment: I did not come across any example where they allow passng parameters to an intent using adb..

Comment: I think you are referring to something like following:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494764/how-to-run-a-specific-android-app-using-terminal looks lik eit is do-able so I am changing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For KK:

```
adb shell am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA --ei android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING 1
```

Change the id 0 or 1 for front and back camera.