# How to choose “front camera” on new intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);

    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

My code is this above, my device is LG Nexus 4 with 4.4.2.

Intent starts with back camera always. I try to change number with 0,1,2 but same result. how can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially, there's no intent that targets the front-facing camera. Your code might work on some phones, though. See [here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19670928/3171854)

Comment: But the official solution is users that choose right camera every time?

Comment: @Danilo: The "official solution" is that you should not care what camera is used. It is up to the third-party camera app that you are invoking, and the user, to determine what camera will be used.

Comment: There is a problem with not knowing which facing is used. Image we get in result is always rotated 90 or -90 degrees depending on camera facing used.