# How to display front camera by default in android studio

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

When clicking on a button I need to open the front camera by default but back camera is displaying. Please give me some idea how to open front camera.

This is my code:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }); Bitmap bmp;
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if ( data != null && data.getExtras() !=  null) {
        bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open "front camera" on android platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform)

Answer (score 1):

This below code should work(without intent) .Refer from [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html)

```
 Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
       int cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                try {
                    cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

If you want to use intent check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667094/intent-does-not-set-the-camera-parameters/19670928#19670928) .I think that this solution may not work for all phones.Check the official [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) for more reference.I suggest that you should not care what camera is used. It is up to the third-party camera app that you are invoking.

Comment: thank u but i need to pass the image am taking through object to some other activity , is there any solution for it

Comment: check this link  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html @SivakumarS

Comment: Thank you , i think it may help me @soham

Comment: @SivakumarS If my answer helps you please accept it or please post your own answer.