# Front camera is not opening in android platform

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera

When I click on capture photo icon in my application, by default it should open  front camera but every time it is opening back camera. I need to change it manually to open front camera.

```
     So can anyone please help me out on the above issue.
```

Below is my code to open front camera mode .

```
    private void getPhotoFromCamera() 
    {
        try 
        {
            PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",1);
            VisitorRegistrationFragment.this.startActivityForResult(intent,FROM_CAMERA);
         } 
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } 
         catch (OutOfMemoryError e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667094/intent-does-not-set-the-camera-parameters/19670928#19670928

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4767832/1182022) answer might help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open "front camera" on android platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform)

Answer (score 1):

Change to use front camera

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",0);
```

Hardcoding this values is a bad idea and should better use

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
```

Comment: I have tried with above code also..but its not working.Previously its working fine but when I upgrade from jellybean to kitkat version the camera is always opening back cam.

Answer (score 1):

This is code to open front camera 
My javafile :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
    public static int count = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Here, we are making a folder named picFolder to store
        // pics taken by the camera using this application.
        final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/";
        File newdir = new File(dir);
        newdir.mkdirs();

        Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Here, the counter will be incremented each time, and the
                // picture taken by camera will be stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg
                // and likewise.
                count++;
                String file = dir + count + ".jpg";
                File newfile = new File(file);
                   try {
                        newfile.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",1);
               // cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
        }
    }
}
```

my Xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="aavid.rks.stackovewrflow.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click pic Using Front camera"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="93dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="93dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

two permission needed :-

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }
        return cam;
}
```

Add the following permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />   
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: I have added the above permissions in manifest file..but now also its opening back camera

Comment: I think the issue is with the camera because I have done all changes which you have commented above .but still its not working

Comment: but front camera is open using above code. this is not enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add this in your **onCreate()** method :

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
    } else {
        currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    }
    camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   camera.startPreview();
```

It worked for me. Hope so it might be helpful for you too.