# Launch front camera with intent

Tags: java, android, android-camera, samsung-mobile, android-camera2

I am trying to open the front camera directly with `Intent`. Below is my code --

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);

            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
        }
```

My manifest file :--

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="some.package">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

This code is not working on S6(7.0). However it is working on S5,S4,Nexus 6P(8.0).

So is this some kind of bug of Samsung or there is something wrong in my code.

I have found some similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174904/front-camera-is-not-opening-in-android-platform) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686203/how-to-launch-front-camera-with-intent/40175503). But not helpful in my case.

Comment: Can you show your manifest file please..?

Comment: Added @UmangBurman

Comment: Looks like it is some kind of a bug, Samsung phones are somewhat buggy here and there as the OS is fully customized. IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to open the front camera directly with Intent

There is nothing for that in the Android SDK.

> Below is my code

There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of different camera apps available for Android. Some are pre-installed; some are user-installed. None have to honor those undocumented `Intent` extras.

> This code is not working on S6(7.0). However it is working on S5,S4,Nexus 6P(8.0).

There are ~20,000+ Android device models. Only some might have a pre-installed camera app that honors those undocumented `Intent` extras.

> So is this some kind of bug of Samsung or there is something wrong in my code.

Samsung's camera app for that particular device simply does not honor those undocumented extras.