# Front camera not working on different devices

Tags: java, android, android-camera, front-camera

```
public class camera extends Activity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "photo";
    private int cameraId = 1;
    private Camera camera = null;
    Button b1, b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_photo);
    }

    public void takephoto() {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
        setSurface();
    }

    private Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream jpg = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                        "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                jpg.write(data);
                jpg.close();

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "written " + data.length + " bytes to /sdcard/JBCameraCapture.jpg");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
        }
    };

    private SurfaceHolder.Callback shCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "surfaceDestroyed callback");
            if (camera != null) {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
            }
            camera = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "surfaceCreated callback");
            startCamera(cameraId);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "surfaceChanged callback ");
        }
    };

    private void setSurface() {
        SurfaceView previewSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_surface);
        previewSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(shCallback);
    }

    protected void startCamera(final int id) {
        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Camera>() {
            @Override
            protected Camera doInBackground(Integer... ids) {
                return openCamera(ids[0]);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Camera c) {
                startPreview(id, c);
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        takephoto();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }.execute(id);
    }

    private static Camera openCamera(int id) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "opening camera " + id);
        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open(id);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "opened camera " + id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        return camera;
    }

    private void startPreview(int id, Camera c) {
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                SurfaceView previewSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_surface);
                SurfaceHolder holder = previewSurfaceView.getHolder();
                c.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera = c;
                cameraId = id;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                c.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have written this code for the front camera but it is not working in all Android devices, in some devices it reboots the phone and in some devices it shows an unfortunate error and in some devices it works properly.

Comment: See the Reference:enter link description here[enter link description here] [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667094/intent-does-not-set-the-camera-parameters/19670928#19670928)

Comment: What errors do you see? For example, some devices don't have front facing camera, so open(1) will fail; others don't have back facing camera, so their front facing camera has id=0, yet others may have 2 cameras on the back, so the front facing id is 2…

Comment: What is the purpose of the AsyncTask here?

Comment: it opens the camera, than it shows FATAL error. android.hardware camera etc