# Take photo with flash via intent

Tags: android, android-camera

Is any solution to put some parameter to Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) that would take photo with flash as default parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Intent` extra to allow you to control the flash mode for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Even if there were, not all camera apps would honor it.

Answer (score -1):

To check if the Android device has a flash available, you can do this simple check :

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

This check will return true if there's a flash available on the device or false if it doesn't.

Read more about : [FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)

Also after doing quite a bit of digging on Camera intent, turns out the only extra parameter you could use is :

```
MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT
```

Reference : [Intent does not set the camera parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667094/intent-does-not-set-the-camera-parameters)

Comment: I believe Stanislav would like to know if there is an option to try enable/disable a flash via Intent, effectively telling the launched app to do that.

Comment: @AlexanderMayatsky I might have misunderstood the question at first, answer updated.