# Invoke Java code from Android command line shell

Tags: android, android-ndk

Does anyone know how to invoke Java code from within a shell on Android?

This is not the other way around. I do not want to invoke shell code from within Java.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494764/how-to-run-a-specific-android-app-using-terminal

Comment: What is the nature of the code you want to invoke?  Is it an activity or service, or rather something else?

Comment: Thanks Henry close enough!