# How to run (not only install) an android application using .apk file?

Tags: android, android-install-apk

Is there any command on `cmd.exe` that would allow me to start the main activity of a particular android application using the `.apk` file of that application. Please note that I know this command which only installs an android application:

```
adb install myapp.apk
```

This command will only install `myapp` onto the emulator and I have to manually run this application from the emulator (by performing single click on its icon).

What I want to do is use a command which not only installs the application but also starts its main activity (please note that I have only its `.apk` file so I don't know what the package name or any activity name is).

Comment: do you find this answer of this question? then please send me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start an application using android ADB tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

Answer (score 98):

You can't install and run in one go - but you can certainly use adb to start your already installed application. Use adb shell am start to fire an intent - you will need to use the correct intent for your application though. A couple of examples:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings
```

will launch Settings, and

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity
```

will launch the Browser. 
If you want to point the Browser at a particular page, do this

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity http://www.google.co.uk
```

If you don't know the name of the activities in the APK, then do this

```
aapt d xmltree <path to apk> AndroidManifest.xml
```

the output content will includes a section like this:

```
   E: activity (line=32)
    A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f080000
    A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f070000
    A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.anonymous.MainWindow"
    A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x3
    A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x1
    A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x80
    E: intent-filter (line=33)
      E: action (line=34)
        A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN"
        XE: (line=34)
```

That tells you the name of the main activity (MainWindow), and you can now run

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.anonymous/.MainWindow
```

Comment: hi thanks for your quick response but i didn't understand your answer... using 'am' command (which you told me) can i start main activity of myapp.apk? (note that i dont know the package name and activity name of myapp)...

Comment: You may have to parse the .apk to identify the main activity (using a tool which can re-textify the packed AndroidManifest.xml), though you may see it turn up in logcat during installation.

Comment: @NoSixties - I cannot see why your suggested edit was rejected! Please try again!

Answer (score 17):

if you're looking for the equivalent of "adb run myapp.apk"

you can use the script shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

(linux and mac only - maybe with cygwin on windows)

linux/mac users can also create a script to run an apk with something like the following:

create a file named "adb-run.sh" with these 3 lines:

```
pkg=$(aapt dump badging $1|awk -F" " '/package/ {print $2}'|awk -F"'" '/name=/ {print $2}')
act=$(aapt dump badging $1|awk -F" " '/launchable-activity/ {print $2}'|awk -F"'" '/name=/ {print $2}')
adb shell am start -n $pkg/$act
```

then "chmod +x adb-run.sh" to make it executable.

now you can simply:

adb-run.sh myapp.apk

The benefit here is that you don't need to know the package name or launchable activity name. Similarly, you can create "adb-uninstall.sh myapp.apk"

Note: This requires that you have aapt in your path. You can find it under the new build tools folder in the SDK

Comment: the link might die, you should include its content here.

Answer (score 9):

This is a solution in shell script:

```
apk="$apk_path"
```

## 1. Install apk

```
adb install "$apk"
sleep 1
```

## 2. Get package name

```
pkg_info=`aapt dump badging "$apk" | head -1 | awk -F " " '{print $2}'`
eval $pkg_info > /dev/null
```

## 3. Start app

```
pkg_name=$name
adb shell monkey -p "${pkg_name}" -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

Answer (score 6):

When you start the app from the GUI, `adb logcat` might show you the corresponding action/category/component:

> $ adb logcat
>   [...]
>   I/ActivityManager( 1607): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity} from pid 1792
>   [...]

Answer (score 5):

First to install your app:

```
adb install -r path\ProjectName.apk
```

The great thing about the -r is it works even if it wasn’t already installed.

To launch MainActivity, so you can launch it like:

`adb shell am start -n com.other.ProjectName/.MainActivity`

Answer (score 3):

I put this in my makefile, right the next line after `adb install ...`

```
adb shell monkey -p `cat .identifier` -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

For this to work there must be a .identifier file with the app's bundle identifier in it, like `com.company.ourfirstapp`

No need to hunt activity name.

Answer (score 2):

I created terminal aliases to install and run an apk using a single command.

```
// I use ZSH, here is what I added to my .zshrc file (config file)
// at ~/.zshrc
// If you use bash shell, append it to ~/.bashrc

# Have the adb accessible, by including it in the PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:path/to/android_sdk/platform-tools/"

# Setup your Android SDK path in ANDROID_HOME variable
export ANDROID_HOME=~/sdks/android_sdk

# Setup aapt tool so it accessible using a single command
alias aapt="$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt"

# Install APK to device
# Use as: apkinstall app-debug.apk
alias apkinstall="adb devices | tail -n +2 | cut -sf 1 | xargs -I X adb -s X install -r $1"
# As an alternative to apkinstall, you can also do just ./gradlew installDebug

# Alias for building and installing the apk to connected device
# Run at the root of your project
# $ buildAndInstallApk
alias buildAndInstallApk='./gradlew assembleDebug && apkinstall ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'

# Launch your debug apk on your connected device
# Execute at the root of your android project
# Usage: launchDebugApk
alias launchDebugApk="adb shell monkey -p `aapt dump badging ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk | grep -e 'package: name' | cut -d \' -f 2` 1"

# ------------- Single command to build+install+launch apk------------#
# Execute at the root of your android project
# Use as: buildInstallLaunchDebugApk
alias buildInstallLaunchDebugApk="buildAndInstallApk && launchDebugApk"
```

> Note: Here I am building, installing and launching the debug apk which is usually in the path: `./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`, when this command is executed from the root of the project
>
> If you would like to install and run any other apk, simply replace the path for debug apk with path of your own apk

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/nisrulz/c1bacaa9d794bf232213304053403680) for the same.
I created this because I was having trouble working with Android Studio build reaching around 28 minutes, so I switched over to terminal builds which were around 3 minutes. You can read more about this [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-i-reduced-my-android-build-times-by-89-4242e51ce946)

**Explanation:**

The one alias that I think needs explanation is the `launchDebugApk` alias.
Here is how it is broken down:

The part `aapt dump badging ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk | grep -e 'package: name` basically uses the `aapt` tool to extract the package name from the apk.

Next, is the command: `adb shell monkey -p com.package.name 1`, which basically uses the `monkey` tool to open up the default launcher activity of the installed app on the connected device. The part of `com.package.name` is replaced by our previous command which takes care of getting the package name from the apk.