# Bitmaps on canvases a bad idea for any game with moving objects

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, sprite, android-canvas

I've been fooling around with canvas with bitmap sprites on and have come to the conclusion that if you want sprites to move on the screen (and still look good) you need to go openGL..

Even a single ball (200x200 pixels) wont move in real time if the background is filled out with a full screen image (a picture of a court or something)

Am I correct that canvas/bitmap is not the way to do it or does it sound like I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've always done that and it works good for me even with around 20 animated sprites. It is laggy on the emulator but not an actual device. OpenGL may still be the better option but don't use the emulator to judge animation quality, it is slower than the slowest actual devices (at least on my pc it is)

Comment: Very true - If you want to see the real performance of an app it's always best to test on a physical device. Personally I dropbox it to my phone and install it any time I want to run a test - It's really quick and you can get a much better feel for your app.

Comment: @TJBiddle: You can install & run it much simpler and faster - by using adb commandline tool. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109234/how-to-runnot-only-install-an-android-application-using-apk-file

Comment: @Martin - Evo's don't play nicely with adb and get disconnected after a few minutes. Thanks for the tip though :)

Comment: @Biskoppen could you provide a code sample where you did your animation using canvas? Maybe there's something in it that's causing it to work harder than it has to