# exec command android native code

Tags: android, c, linux, adb

I am trying to launch an android applications from native code.

In adb shell we can launch applications using "am" command.

Link:

[How to run (not only install) an android application using .apk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109234/how-to-runnot-only-install-an-android-application-using-apk-file)

Is there any way to invoke this "am" command through C code?

I tried the following line but exec is returning -1:

```
  ret = execl("/system/bin/am", "start", "-a", "android.intent.action.MAIN",
 "-n", "com.android.settings/.Settings", (char *)NULL);
```

Is this right or not?

Comment: Tried where? In Android? In PC?

Comment: in android only.. i put it in a working c code in android.... exec is failing

Comment: Does `/system/bin/am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings` works launched from terminal?

Comment: ya its working in adb shell.. it will launch the settings menu

Comment: do we need run exec in vfork or something... ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer...
I 'exec'ed the shell itself and gave it the command... It worked

```
ret = execl("/system/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n   com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity", (char *)NULL);
```

Thanks to m0skit0, Padma Kumar, Yuri ...

Comment: It's not entirely clear why using a shell would make a difference here.  However note that calling an exec family function without first calling fork() **replaces** the calling program - which, if that was an android app will look like a crash.

Answer (score 0):

you should use  system() family method  ,first  it will fork child process and invoke  shell then return,so it will not  block  android main thread

Comment: This should maybe have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: system will block whatever thread it is called from.  So don't call this from your main thread.