# How can I launch and execute Vending.apk on the Android Emulator from adb

Tags: android, shell, adb, aapt

I've been trying to install Vending.apk into my emulator w/o success.  It says it already exists and fails to replace it when I use adb install -r.  The icon does not show up on the screen so I can't tap it to launch the Google Play marketplace.

Therefore, I thought I could run it from my PC (MacOSX) using adb like this:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.vending/.Vending
```

I constructed the above from examples that work in this article:
[How to run (not only install) an android application using .apk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109234/how-to-runnot-only-install-an-android-application-using-apk-file)

And I unzipped the AndroidManifest.xml file using info from this method to see if I could discover the activity name, but no luck:

```
aapt dump xmltree <apk-file> AndroidManifest.xml
```

I guess I need to know the exact command to execute the vending apk because I can't seem to find the correct Activity class.  adb shell am start keeps giving me error type 3, Activity class does not exist.

Thanks

Comment: @mcruiseon, he is not asking about that, I believe. He is asking about how to *run* the *Android Market/Play app*.

Comment: @DavidCesarino, you are correct.  I am asking specifically about running the Android Market/Play app, and what Activity Class I would need to specify to the "am start" shell command.

Comment: It's easier to find in the Internet the articles about how to install Google MarketPlace on the emulator. Do you need this?

Answer (score 11):

You can try this:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity
```

Comment: Great... with aapt I couldn't find the package main activity, how weird is that?