# Execution of Dalvik VM directly on desktop

Tags: dalvik

Is it possible to execute task directly on Dalvik VM machine as we run other virtual machines on desktop system?

Comment: Is there any tutorial or any link that can help me to run tasks directly DVM

Comment: I mean through command line writing some commands that executes .apk file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i have understood your question correctly :I'm considering `task` mentioned in question as apk (If so then following answer might help ypu)

If you have your target connected to host then you can use two of the most common command tools :

```
 activity manager (am)  
 package manager (pm)
```

First install apllication through command line `adb install <path_to_apk>`

For example : `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings` 
will launch settings .

If you  don't know that package name or any activity name then start application from GUI ,then capture the logs using logcat it will show you action,category,component .

After knowing action,category,component use `am` command as shown above

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109234/how-to-runnot-only-install-an-android-application-using-apk-file)

Also check [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#am)

And for Dalvik Debugger Support check this [link](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/dalvik/docs/debugger.html)

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is run a command-line program on the device, it's pretty straightforward.  The Android sources include a document describing how to do it in [dalvik/docs/hello-world.html](http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/hello-world.html) [(original docs)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/docs/hello-world.html), including instructions for using a debugger.

Here's the example from that page:

```
% echo 'class Foo {'\
> 'public static void main(String[] args) {'\
> 'System.out.println("Hello, world"); }}' > Foo.java
% javac Foo.java
% dx --dex --output=foo.jar Foo.class
% adb push foo.jar /sdcard
% adb shell dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/foo.jar Foo
Hello, world
```