# Connect from MonkeyTalk to Android HEADLESS emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, monkeytalk

**Question**

Is there a way how to connect to an Android emulator in headless mode?

**Problem**

I was able to connect. I received from the MonkeyTalk IDE

```
Connection type set to: Android Emulator or Tethered Device
```

Which should be fine according to [MT documentation.](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-getting-started/connect-your-app)

The problem is I can't play any commands as the buttons are disabled. Hope, it's possible otherwise there is no use for the Continous Integration.

**===EDIT===**

Ok, so it seems, and it's written in the MT docs, that the app has to be running already.
So, how is it possible to open up my app in the headless mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is here.

**1. Install your APK**

```
adb.exe install -r ${path2urApk}
```

The **-r** flag replaces the old apk.

**2. Run the application**

No matter whether the screen is locked or not this works...

```
adb shell am start -n your.pakackge/.somewhere.blah.TheActivity
```

The correct category and activity can be found using logcat: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9077186/1075289