# How to start and stop android service from a adb shell?

Tags: android, service, adb

I need to write a shell script to start and stop an android service .

Comment: I  tried to initiate a  `adb shell whatsapp `  backup .. I could find a `service ( com.whatsapp.backup.google.GoogleBackupService )  `  that sounded close to whatsapp backup service but no `activity `    for `com.whatsapp`  . Tinkered with the command with various combos but it gave an error. Here  is the output. Due to comment limitation I cant put it here directly. How do I get this done ?  `Whatsapp Chat backup over adb? `  https://paste.c-net.org/AlreadyLeveled

Answer (score 71):

I'm a beginner in Android, but got it working like this:

in AndroidManifest.xml, make sure you, inside `<application>`, have something like this:

```
<service android:name="com.some.package.name.YourServiceSubClassName" android:permission="com.some.package.name.YourServiceSubClassName">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.some.package.name.YourServiceSubClassName"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

where `YourServiceSubClassName` extend `android.app.Service` is your java class that is the service. Where `com.some.package` is the package name, for me both in AndroidManifest.xml and in Java. 
Used [a javabeat.net article](http://www.javabeat.net/2013/04/how-to-write-androidmanifest-xml/) as help, look for `<service>`

Note also, supposedly between the package name and the class name there should be `.service.` in the text, I guess this is some convention, but for me this caused `ClassNotFoundException` that I'm yet to solve.

Then, install your apk. I did from eclipse but also `adb install -r yourApkHere.apk` should work. Uninstall is `adb uninstall com.some.package.name`, btw.

You can **start** it from host system like this, thanks [Just a Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11867567/611007) and [MrRoy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8469325/611007):

```
adb shell am startservice com.some.package.name/.YourServiceSubClassName
```

interestingly, I didn't need `-n`.

To **stop**, I use

```
adb shell am force-stop com.some.package.name
```

Hope it helps.

As I'm a beginner, please feel freet to edit/comment to fix any misconceptions (eg. probably regarding `.service.` in the component (?) name).

Comment: So, that's why I get this error? $ am startservice com.adguard.android/.vpn.AdguardVpnService                                                                                           
Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.adguard.android/.vpn.AdguardVpnService }
Error: Requires permission android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE

Comment: I  tried to initiate a  `adb shell whatsapp `  backup .. I could find a `service ( com.whatsapp.backup.google.GoogleBackupService )  `  that sounded close to whatsapp backup service but no `activity `    for `com.whatsapp`  . Tinkered with the command with various combos but it gave an error. Here  is the output. Due to comment limitation I cant put it here directly. How do I get this done ?  `Whatsapp Chat backup over adb? `  https://paste.c-net.org/AlreadyLeveled

Answer (score 27):

**Starting** a service:

```
adb shell am startservice ...
```

> start a Service.  Options are:
>       --user  | current: Specify which user to run as; if not
>           specified then run as the current user.

**Stopping** a service:

```
adb shell am stopservice ...
```

> stop a Service.  Options are:
>       --user  | current: Specify which user to run as; if not
>           specified then run as the current user.

Answer (score 22):

You may get an error "*Error: app is in background *" while using

```
adb shell am startservice
```

in Oreo (26+). This requires services in the foreground. 
Use the following.

```
adb shell am start-foreground-service com.some.package.name/.YourServiceSubClassName
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want to run the script in adb shell, then I am trying to do the same, but with an application. I think you can use "am start" command

usage: am [subcommand] [options]

```
start an Activity: am start [-D] [-W] <INTENT>
    -D: enable debugging
    -W: wait for launch to complete

**start a Service: am startservice <INTENT>**

send a broadcast Intent: am broadcast <INTENT>

start an Instrumentation: am instrument [flags] <COMPONENT>
    -r: print raw results (otherwise decode REPORT_KEY_STREAMRESULT)
    -e <NAME> <VALUE>: set argument <NAME> to <VALUE>
    -p <FILE>: write profiling data to <FILE>
    -w: wait for instrumentation to finish before returning

start profiling: am profile <PROCESS> start <FILE>
stop profiling: am profile <PROCESS> stop

start monitoring: am monitor [--gdb <port>]
    --gdb: start gdbserv on the given port at crash/ANR

<INTENT> specifications include these flags:
    [-a <ACTION>] [-d <DATA_URI>] [-t <MIME_TYPE>]
    [-c <CATEGORY> [-c <CATEGORY>] ...]
    [-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE> ...]
    [--esn <EXTRA_KEY> ...]
    [--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE> ...]
    [-e|--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE> ...]
    [-n <COMPONENT>] [-f <FLAGS>]
    [--grant-read-uri-permission] [--grant-write-uri-permission]
    [--debug-log-resolution]
    [--activity-brought-to-front] [--activity-clear-top]
    [--activity-clear-when-task-reset] [--activity-exclude-from-recents]
    [--activity-launched-from-history] [--activity-multiple-task]
    [--activity-no-animation] [--activity-no-history]
    [--activity-no-user-action] [--activity-previous-is-top]
    [--activity-reorder-to-front] [--activity-reset-task-if-needed]
    [--activity-single-top]
    [--receiver-registered-only] [--receiver-replace-pending]
    [<URI>]
```

Comment: That help page really does not help you figure out how to specify the intent.   In particular, the syntax for <COMPONENT> is mysterious.

Comment: @pzulw [Just a Tim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11867567/611007) combined with [MrRoy's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8469325/611007) and putting stuff in AndroidManifest.xml according to [<service> on this link](http://www.javabeat.net/2013/04/how-to-write-androidmanifest-xml/) helped.

Comment: I  tried to initiate a  `adb shell whatsapp `  backup .. I could find a `service ( com.whatsapp.backup.google.GoogleBackupService )  `  that sounded close to whatsapp backup service but no `activity `    for `com.whatsapp`  . Tinkered with the command with various combos but it gave an error. Here  is the output. Due to comment limitation I cant put it here directly. How do I get this done ?  `Whatsapp Chat backup over adb? `  https://paste.c-net.org/AlreadyLeveled

Answer (score 12):

I can start service through

```
am startservice com.xxx/.service.XXXService
```

but i don't know how to stop it yet.

Comment: You may use a broadcast receiver to stop a service, and then send broadcast to that receiver.

Answer (score 11):

To stop a service, you have to find service name using:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity services <your package>
```

for example:
adb shell dumpsys activity services com.xyz.something

This will list services running for your package.
Output should be similar to:

```
ServiceRecord{xxxxx u0 com.xyz.something.beta/xyz.something.abc.XYZService}
```

Now select your service and run:

```
adb shell am stopservice <service_name>
```

For example:

```
adb shell am stopservice com.xyz.something.beta/xyz.something.abc.XYZService
```

similarly, to start service:

```
adb shell am startservice <service_name>
```

To access service, your service(in AndroidManifest.xml) should set exported="true"

```
<!-- Service declared in manifest -->
<service
    android:name=".YourServiceName"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.your.package.name.YourServiceName"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to add `android:exported="true"` to start service from ADB command line. Then your manifest looks something like this:

```
<!-- Service declared in manifest -->
<service
    android:name=".YourServiceName"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.your.package.name.YourServiceName"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</service> <!-- Note: Service is exported to start it using ADB command -->
```

And then from ADB

To start service:

`adb shell am startservice com.your.package.name/.YourServiceName`

To stop service (on Marshmallow):

`adb shell am stopservice com.your.package.name/.YourServiceName`

To stop service (on Jelly Bean):

`adb shell am force-stop com.your.package.name`

Answer (score 8):

You should set the android:exported attribute of the service to "true", in order to allow other components to invoke it. In the AndroidManifest.xml file, add the following attribute:

```
<service android:exported="true" ></service>
```

Then, you should be able to start the service via adb:

```
adb shell am startservice com.package.name/.YourServiceName
```

For more info about the android:exported attribute see [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html).

Answer (score 6):

Responding to pzulw's feedback to sandroid about specifying the intent.

The format of the component name is described in the api docs for [ComponentName.unflattenFromString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html#unflattenFromString%28java.lang.String%29)

> It splits the string at the first '/', taking the part before as the package name and the part after as the class name. As a special convenience (to use, for example, when parsing component names on the command line), if the '/' is immediately followed by a '.' then the final class name will be the concatenation of the package name with the string following the '/'. Thus "com.foo/.Blah" becomes package="com.foo" class="com.foo.Blah".

Answer (score 3):

`am startservice <INTENT>`

or actually from the OS shell

`adb shell am startservice <INTENT>`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still confused about how to define the service name parameter, the forward slash goes immediately after the application package name in the fully qualified class name.

So given an application package name of: `app.package.name`

And a full path to the service of: `app.package.name.example.package.path.MyServiceClass`

Then the command would look like this:

```
adb shell am startservice app.package.name/.example.package.path.MyServiceClass
```

Comment:  damn I was struggling with this as it's not explained properly anywhere - thank you