# Android adb shell am startservice: Error not found

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to start the service from adb shell. There already is similar question: [How to start and stop android service from a adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415997/how-to-start-and-stop-android-service-from-a-adb-shell) 
However, when I start service with:

```
adb shell am startservice com.mypackage/com.mypackage.service.MyService
```

I receive this message:

```
Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=com.mypackage/com.mypackage.service.MyService }
Error: Not found; no service started.
```

I declare service in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application>
  ...
  <service
    android:name="com.mypackage.service.MyService"
    android:label="@string/local_service_label"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
  </service>
</application>
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
adb shell am startservice -n com.mypackage/.service.MyService
```

Update (Per `adb shell am help start-service`):

`-n` `<COMPONENT_NAME>`

Comment: A single command may answer the question, but it would be useful to explain what `-n` does. You might also want to indent any code by 4 spaces.

Comment: "am startservice" help lists [-n <COMPONENT>]
(it does not relate to line numbers)

Answer (score 4):

Consider the below as an example

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:description="@string/Desciption"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.nandhan.myservice" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>        
</application>
```

Then I would start the service as below

**adb shell am startservice com.nandhan.myservice/.MyService**

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the service failing to start was `com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService`.

> Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.xxx.xxx/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService }
>   Error: Not found; no service started.

Turns out my android device was missing something. To disable it, go to `preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run` and uncheck `Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy (default enabled)`.

[image: disable instant run]

According to that screenshot, it's better to keep it and indeed, I'd be happier with that feature. At least I ran with extra logging and sent feedback to google. I just needed a build asap so no instant run for me today ;)

Answer (score 1):

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xyz.path">

...

<application

...

    <service android:name=".MyService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.xyz.path.MY_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

...
```

Command:

```
adb shell am startservice -n com.xyz.path/.MyService
```