# Interact with android notification action from ADB Shell

Tags: android, shell, android-notifications, adb

I have an Android(7) phone and a Linux pc. By enabling USB debugging and using the terminal of my pc, I am able to read the notifications of my phone using the command:
`adb shell dumpsys notification --noredact`

Now, there are some notifications in android in which we can interact with the app directly from the notification. For example, in a Whatsapp notification, there are usually two buttons: *Reply* & *Mark as read*. In YouTube, there are options like *Play*, *Turn off*, *Watch later*. In the output of the above command, these options are visible in the following form:

```
actions={
        [0] "Reply" -> PendingIntent{6becf48: PendingIntentRecord{87b8050 com.whatsapp startService (whitelist: +30s0ms)}}
        [1] "Mark as read" -> PendingIntent{c1661e1: PendingIntentRecord{b8e3249 com.whatsapp startService (whitelist: +30s0ms)}}
      }
```

I have two questions:

1. Can we interact with these options from adb shell? For example, is there any command like `adb shell <SOME COMMAND> 'Message to be sent in whatsapp with reply option'` which will send the text as a reply in whatsapp without opening the app?
2. Is it possible to swipe the notifications using any adb command? (Not the `adb shell input swipe x0 y0 x1 y1`, it requires to unlock the phone each time)

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

Here is what I found that may be relevant to this question.

I think that I have to somehow launch the specific intent linked to the mentioned PendingIntent id (in this case `6becf48` or `87b8050`)

Using tthe command `adb shell dumpsys activity intents > output.txt` and then searching for `87b8050` in `output.txt`, I found the name of the intent. It was as follows:

```
  * PendingIntentRecord{87b8050 com.whatsapp startService (whitelist: +30s0ms)}
    uid=10104 packageName=com.whatsapp type=startService flags=0x0
    requestIntent=act=com.whatsapp.intent.action.DIRECT_REPLY_FROM_MESSAGE dat=content://com.whatsapp.provider.contact/contacts/2256 cmp=com.whatsapp/.notification.DirectReplyService (has extras)
    whitelistDuration=+30s0ms
```

Now I think that it may be possible to launch the intent `com.whatsapp.intent.action.DIRECT_REPLY_FROM_MESSAGE` using `adb shell am` command, and passing the intent id and message as some parameters.

(Just like we can launch Whatsapp from adb with `am` command, it should be possible to launch the pendingIntent also.)

Comment: Can anybody help with this? I am stuck at this point for long. 

(Also you can up-vote the question. Currently I cannot offer bounty.)

Comment: How do I attract attention to this question? I really need help for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no way to access not exported component from a non-root ADB.**

In theory you can run this code to execute "Reply" action:

```sh
adb shell am startservice --user 10104  \
  -a "com.whatsapp.intent.action.DIRECT_REPLY_FROM_MESSAGE" \
  -d "content://com.whatsapp.provider.contact/contacts/2256" \
  -n "com.whatsapp/.notification.DirectReplyService" \
  --es extra_key extra_string_value
  com.whatsapp
```

`--user` - user uid,
`-a` - action from `requestIntent.act`
`-d` - data_uri from `requestIntent.dat`
`-n` - component from `requestIntent.cmp`
`--es EXTRA_KEY extra_string_value` - extra keys/values, which application should accepts. It's optional, and defined in the application, actually this action accepts extra keys, see `(has extras)`, it depends of application and could be in the application documentation

[Intent documentation, commands, arguments and options](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#am)

[Whatsapp Android intent system](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/im-an-android-developer-how-can-i-integrate-whatsapp-with-my-app)

Comment: If it is not possible to access a non-exported component, then how do apps like PushBullet or wearOS apps work? Cannot we mimic the procedure inside ADB shell?

Comment: @SohamSaha  PushBullet, KDEconnect, wearOS and other similar applications uses special access in the android settings, adb designed for debugging and does not have that access, for grant access for adb you must use a build variant that includes `android:exported` in the build configuration of your application for each service (for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/17019102/1772410), of course this does not apply to applications from android market. Instead of access via adb shell, you can write an application for android from which you can access notifications