# Telnet to Android Emulator with puTTy

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, telnet

I am using windows 7 and I need to Telnet to my android emulator to be able to run a location app.  How would I go about doing that?  The only tutorials I am finding have been for linux...

Answer (score 19):

Use **RAW** as Connection Type and not Telnet. 
Use the following parameters. 
**hostname: localhost

port: 5554**

Answer (score 5):

You 1st need to enable telnet because windows 7 has it disable by default:
http://www.itdoescompute.com/2009/10/29/how-to-enable-telnet-in-windows-7/

Alternative, download Putty @ http://www.putty.org/ and connect to your Android. I believe its "localhost:5554"

You could simply connect to your Android via the ADB Shell instead of online; `adb -e shell`

**How to use ADB Shell:** 
http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-use-android-adb-command-line-tool/

**Launching an App, Answer by Cristian ([view profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244296/cristian))**
[How to start an application using android ADB tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

Comment: I have telnet enabled already, it's just been forever and I couldn't remember how to do it.  How does the adb -e shell work?  Do i just put that in and it works?

Comment: You just uploaded it.  Thanks for the assistance and the quick answer!

Comment: Your welcome, just enable debugging mode and make sure you have adb and all that install (you should if you are developing for android) then just open a console and change directory to the android-sdk, where adb is located and then you can launch an app if you wish. Check my updated answer for link.

Comment: Putty must need some sort of configuration. When using it to telnet, I get `KO: Forbidden binary request. Aborting` even when typing `help` as suggested by the welcome message (`Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands`)

Comment: @ImreL That is the key Imre... when selecting `telnet` my putty is closing every time I hit enter. this made me crazy like hell...I hate putty since then!!