# Start application on phone from ADB

Tags: android, android-activity, adb

i want to start an application on the phone through adb tools.
I follow this thread [Link]

[1]: [How to start an application using android ADB tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools) but, for example if i want to start the Angry Bird game how do i can discover the MAIN activity of package?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install the app [AppXplore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.androidapp.AppExplore) from Google Play, you can inspect your installed applications and learn the **package name** and the **Activities** in the APK.

I've verified it just now and it worked by starting Adobe Reader from adb shell:

```
am start -n com.adobe.reader/com.adobe.reader.AdobeReader
```

Answer (score 0):

We can start any application using am-:activity manager

```
    adb shell am start android.intent.action.VIEW
    adb shell am start com.android.Browser
```