# Calling an activity from outside the application in android

Tags: java, android, testing, android-activity, adb

I want to test all the activities of my application by calling outside from the application.

Is it possible? Currently I can only call the main activity from adb. Is it possible to launch other activity?

One solution might be in the android manifest I declare all activities as main activity. Is it feasible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start an application using android ADB tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

Comment: My goal is not to start an application, rather start from a certain activity.

Comment: Right, but the answer covers starting a specific activity of an application from ADB.

Comment: yes I saw that later, but for more specific title i think this question should stay as developers can get it directly from google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch any activity from adb shell

```
adb shell am start -n package-name/activity-1-name
```