# How to compile a whole android project as JAR for using in Delphi application?

Tags: java, android, delphi, jar

I would like to merge our Java (Android) development with the Delphi XE7 mobile (FMX) project, and seems like the best way is to have a JAR which contains a whole Java based mobile application.

- Is it possible to compile Android project with it's intents and resources as JAR, and if it is - how to?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12905129/80901):

Android uses the Dalvik VM, whereas you need the Java VM to run a jar-file. So you can't run a jar-file on Android.

Comment: Emh.. I don't wanna run it, I would like to use it as a library which contains intents, just like Windows DLL's can contains windowses and resources.

Comment: @YordanY please clarify the term `compile` you used in your question, and how the Android device should use the JAR