# adb start(run) .apk that is in system/app

Tags: android, adb

I am needing a way to start up an apk I have put into my system/app on a rooted device from adb. (In the shell or out of shell are both fine)

.apk is pushed onto device using adb.

I have found the way to do this if installed normally but that is not what I need as this app needs to be in system/app for permission reasons.

Can someone please help or point me in the right direction thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try to use adb install xxx.apk? I don't know whether it works by only pushing the file to system/app.

Comment: It puts the installed app into data/app if we use adb install xxx.apk and I want it in system/app

Answer (score 2):

After pushing to system, 
be sure to set permisions, 
then reboot device and launch from adb like any other app.

on reboot the system app will be "installed"

Comment: adb shell am start com.test.hellopushtest/com.test.hellopushtest.MainActivity         does not work after reboot is there some other start method your thinking of?

Comment: yeah thats prety much right look here tho [At this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools) you may have to only use com.test.hellopushtest/.MainActivity

Comment: Thanks for the help but this doesn't work already tried all sorts of combinations we no sucess

Comment: only the HelloPushTest.apk file can be found and there for the com.test.hellopushtest lines do not work and neither will HellPushTest.apk/com.test.hellopushtest.MainActivity ...ect

Comment: Have you set permisions on the file after pushing it to system/app `adb shell chmod 0644 /system/app/yourapp.apk` (need to reboot for it to take affecct)

Comment: yes it just won't let me call the start command on it. Its ok found a work around seems the BroadCastReciever still gets initialized on reboot of device so I can use this to get app running

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command:

```
adb remount
adb push apkfilename /system/app
adb reboot
```

This will make that apk file as a system application.