# Google Glass - launching an apk installed via adb install

Tags: google-glass

How do you launch an .apk on your Google Glass device that you installed via adb install?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools):

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

or

```
 adb shell am start -n com.package.name/.ActivityName
```

Comment: if you don't know the name of the package/activity you can try the additional answer I added to the answer linked above (mac/linux)

Comment: @dljava that is a neat hack :)

Comment: To find out the name of your packages using adb shell pm list packages -f. 

also graphically if you use the chrome adb tool

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adb/dpngiggdglpdnjdoaefidgiigpemgage?hl=en-US

Answer (score 1):

The best option just now is use Launchy (https://github.com/kaze0/launchy) or use intent-filter to start your application when that intent-filter is called.
For example:

```
<manifest ....
       ......
       <application ....
            ......
            <activity .....
                 .....
                 <intent-filter>
                     <action android:name="com.google.glass.action.ACTION_GO_TO_SETTINGS" />
                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 </intent-filter>
            </activity>
       </application>
  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the Activity name:

Launchy no longer works with XE 16 or 17. Glass Launcher does work though since it uses the GDK.

Eclipse version here: https://github.com/justindriggers/Glass-Launcher

Android Studio version here: https://github.com/Splaktar/Glass-Launcher