# Android: launch app info dialog via adb shell am

Tags: android, shell, settings, adb, launch

I'm trying to write a script which will launch the "app info" system dialog via adb for an app I'm testing.

I have done some investigation and came up with this command, which will launch "app info" but fails with a force close (NullPointerException in logcat):

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails -es com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName com.my.app -es pkg com.my.app
```

Seems that the package name isn't being properly passed.

What is the correct way to pass the package name parameter to the `am` command in this case?

Comment: Try out this one: adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails

Comment: is that the whole command? I can't see how to pass the package name as a parameter to the InstalledAppDetails app.

Answer (score 10):

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS -d package:<package-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Also, check this:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567928/4409113

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

---

**http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html#am**

> You can also issue an activity manager command directly from adb
>   without entering a remote shell.

For example:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

Seems like, `start -a` is a good way.