# How can I launch the App Info screen for my app through ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I want to launch the App Info screen for my app through adb. I tried to fire an intent using "adb shell am start" but nothing seems to work. I need something that works at least for API levels 18 and 19. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

Comment: I want to start the info screen for the app, not the app itself

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589910/android-launch-app-info-dialog-via-adb-shell-am

Answer (score 7):

Open App Info

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS package:com.your.packagename
```

For Example: if you want to open Chrome App Info

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS package:com.android.chrome
```

Answer (score -1):

```
adb shell am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname
```

Comment: This starts the app itself. What I want to do is start the App Info screen of the app, the one where you can uninstall the app, force stop, clear data, etc.

Comment: Not sure, that is possible through the adb. You can try to check Settings application manifest (you should decompile app) and find Activities and intent-filters, that are used by details screen. But I am not sure, that you will archive your target

Comment: This doesn't do what was asked