# How to delete an app from adb without knowing it's package name?

Tags: android, adb

I can delete apps (that I code myself and install through the SDK) using this command:

```
adb uninstall com.company.apppackage
```

How do I uninstall this through the command line using `adb` if I do not know the package name?

For example, if an app shows up in the Android main menu as "My Application", how can I delete it if I do not know it's package name?

Or alternatively, is there a way to somehow know an apps internal package name?

Comment: I think you cannot Delete an Application with adb without providing it's appropriate Package Name.

Comment: then, is there a way to know an application's package name from the phone operation system? Since I can delete apps that I code myself, using `adb uninstall com.company.apppackage` as well as delete it from `Setting > apps > Installed Apps` on the phone, I am assuming the package information is still inside the app somewhere

Comment: using a script:
adb-uninstall myapp.apk

see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools/17289998#17289998

Answer (score 77, accepted):

try:

```
adb root
```

Then enter adb shell

```
adb shell
```

Find out your apps package name:

```
pm list packages | grep "your app name/something related to your app name"
```

Then use:

```
adb uninstall
```

OR

```
pm uninstall
```

Comment: I think the package list will only be shown in rooted devices, please correct me.

Comment: `pm list packages|grep <Application name>` without inverted commas works like a charm !

Comment: Thanks!! 
`}catch(CommentTooShortException);`

Comment: @salaman: I intentionally put the double quotes to understand it as text :)

Comment: For me, the `adb root` step was not necessary.

Comment: pm list packages works without root (at least on Lollipop, but I'm sure it does on others as well.) Then pm uninstall <package name from list packages>. Also adb uninstall <packagename> only works after exitting shell. pm works in shell.

Comment: if it's still doesn't uninstall then use `pm uninstall --user -1 "packagename"`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a nice tutorial about getting information (Name, Package name, icon, etc) about Installed Applications on your Android Device, emulator.

This helper util/class retrieves all installed apps with the application name, package name, version-number and code as well as the icons. The method getPackages() returns an ArrayList with all the apps.

```
class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;

    private void prettyPrint() {
        Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
    }
}

class PackageInfoUtil {
    public static ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
        ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
        final int max = apps.size();
        for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
            apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
        }
        return apps;
    }

    public static ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
        ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
        List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

        for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);

            if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
                continue ;
            }

            PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
            newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
            newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
            newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
            newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
            res.add(newInfo);
        }

        return res; 
    }
}
```

After determining the Application's Package name, just delete/uninstall the application using adb.