# How do I uninstall an app from virtual device without having access to the virtual device

Tags: android, virtual-machine, genymotion, vdi

A package (an app) that I installed on a virtual device has resulted in the virtual device crashing on start up. The error logs directly point at the package I recently installed, which launches at start up and immediately crashes the whole system. I would like to know how this app can be removed now that I no longer can boot up the virtual device.

Update: Solution is to do as pointed out in the answer below and uninstall it using `adb`.

Comment: How did you install an app without access to the device? I'm thinking whatever method you used would be a good starting point.

Comment: Can you explain a little? Maybe you can use `adb` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the package name, use can use `adb` as follows:

```
adb uninstall com.example.package_name
```

Note that the package name isn't the same as the app's name.  If you don't know the package name, then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755739/how-to-delete-an-app-from-adb-without-knowing-its-package-name) for how to find out.