# How to launch or run an apk installed via adb on Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I wanted to share my experience on how to run an android app on Google Glass after installing it. In case, app does not have voice triggers defined and cannot be launched by 'OK Glass..', how can you run an app?

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from posts in Stackoverflow including this post: [How to start an application using android ADB tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

After connecting your glass to your computer, you have two options (These has been tested on mac):

1) How to launch/run an apt installed via adb if we know the activity/package name:

adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName

adb shell am start -n com.package.name/.ActivityName

** If you need to find out the list of installed packages on your glass:

adb shell 'pm list packages -f'

2) How to launch/run an apt if we don’t know the activity/package name?

a)   create a file named "adb-run.sh" with these 3 lines:

pkg=$(aapt dump badging $1|awk -F" " '/package/ {print $2}'|awk -F"'" '/name=/ {print $2}')

act=$(aapt dump badging $1|awk -F" " '/launchable-activity/ {print $2}'|awk -F"'" '/name=/ {print $2}')

adb shell am start -n $pkg/$act

b) "chmod +x adb-run.sh" to make it executable

c) adb-run.sh myapp.apk

Note: This requires that you have aapt in your path. You can find it under the new build tools folder in the SDK:

echo ‘export PATH=$PATH:/Users/USERNAME/LOCATIONofSDK/platform-tools/:/Users/USERNAME/LOCATIONofSDK/build-tools/android-4.3/’ >> ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [ChromeADB](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeadb/fhdoijgfljahinnpbolfdimpcfoicmnm?hl=en) ... a great extension that does not need all the command line work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use launchy.
Just install this app on Glass and then go to the settings... launchy will start and provide you the ability to run the APKs you've installed.

https://github.com/kaze0/launchy

Comment: I can see the icon for launch but it has only one app in it while many are installed.