# How to run (regular) android app on Google Glass without having a voice trigger

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I wanted to share my experience since I believe many people who has a Google Glass wants to test how to install an android apk which was not designed for Google Glass. If you know other ways, please share below.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you know the activity/package name:

   ```
   adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
   adb shell am start -n com.package.name/.ActivityName
   ```
2. If you don’t know the activity/package name: (Credit: [How to start an application using android ADB tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools))

   a. create a file named `adb-run.sh` with these 3 lines:

   ```
   pkg=$(aapt dump badging $1|awk -F" " '/package/ {print $2}' | awk -F"'" '/name=/ {print $2}')
   act=$(aapt dump badging $1|awk -F" " '/launchable-activity/ {print $2}' | awk -F"'" '/name=/ {print $2}')
   adb shell am start -n $pkg/$act
   ```

   b. `chmod +x adb-run.sh` to make it executable

   c. `adb-run.sh myapp.apk`

Note: This requires that you have `aapt` in your path. You can find it under the new build tools folder in the SDK:

```
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/LOCATIONofSDK/platform-tools:/LOCATIONofSDK/build-tools/android-4.3' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [Launchy](https://github.com/kaze0/launchy) which allows you to scroll through a list of all apps on the device. The code has recently been updated to allow launching through a voice trigger.