# Cannot launch activity from adb

Tags: android

I have the following in my AndroidManifest.xml (I just added a second activity to the default project):

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name="com.example.com.testapp.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.example.com.testapp.TestActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.testapp.action.TEST_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I want to launch the TestActivity using adb command. I tried:

```
./adb shell am start -a com.testapp.action.TEST_ACTION
```

But it gives the error:

```
 Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=com.testapp.action.TEST_ACTION flg=0x10000000 }
```

Can someone please explain why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

Edit :

Can anyone tell a way to just use action to launch the 'TestActivity'.

Answer (score 6):

try using:
`adb shell "am start -n com.example.com.testapp/.TestActivity -a com.testapp.action.TEST_ACTION"`

or

`adb shell "am start com.example.com.testapp -a com.testapp.action.TEST_ACTION"`

hope that works.

Comment: The first one works. Why can't I just use action to start the activity ?

Comment: One doesn't need the action part in the first case.

Comment: You have to choose activity to run the action connected with that activity.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should add the code below into your intentfilter

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `adb shell am start -n com.mypackage.name/com.mypackage.name.TEST_ACTION` (replace the package names and activity names as needed)

Take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what [陈薛星](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5386924/%E9%99%88%E8%96%9B%E6%98%9F) wrote, in the ["Android developer guide on Intent Filters"](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) under "Category Test", it states

> Note: Android automatically applies the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category to all implicit intents passed to startActivity() and startActivityForResult(). If you want your activity to receive implicit intents, it must include a category for "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" in its intent filters, as shown in the previous  example.

So you need to add
`<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` to your intent filter.

This will match an implicit intent. (Several other answers show how to target a class explicity).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried every posibble combinations of this but the BEST one that worked out was this one

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.emanuelef.remote_capture/.activities.MainActivity`

Here com.emanuelef.remote_caputure is the package i wanted to open and to get the various activities of the package you can use this command

> adb shell dumpsys package com.emanuelef.remote_capture | grep "Activity Resolver"