# Missing launcher icon of ADB-installed app on the phone

Tags: android, apk

After developing for years on iOS I am beginning android development at the moment . Now I am starting to release my first app. I installed my debug signed APK file on a phone like this:

```
$ adb -s HT35HW917059 -d install app/app-***-debug.apk
```

I can start the app using adb without problems (the app launches):

```
$ adb -s HT35HW917059 shell am start -n ...
```

However, I cannot find an app icon on my phone, to start the app? What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start an application using android ADB tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

Comment: Erik, post your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Have you changed the default ic_launcher.png?

Comment: Restarting my Android phone worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check in your AndroidManifest.xml that your activity has the correct [Intent filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
    <!-- This activity is the main entry, should appear in app launcher -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I am sure he has this, he wants to start via command line using adb.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Are you sure? He ends the question with "However, I cannot find an app icon on my phone, to start the app? What am I missing?"

Comment: He would have to had gone to the `AndroidManifest.xml` and actually delete this from the `MainActivity`. I'll ask him to show it.

Comment: Now you changed the title of the question to match your answer. I have never seen anyone do that before. You should have asked him first.

Comment: The first title was so misleading that at least two persons misread the question. He is able to launch the app from ADB but not from the launcher.  Doesn't the edit clarify that?

Comment: I am just saying, let's let him clarify first so it is not confusing.

Comment: Actually that was the problem. Thanks!