# ADB start intent sms android that lists all available SMS

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I tried to find a way to start the SMS intent in Android (Samsung) with ADB :

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.mms/.ui.ConversationComposer
```

I managed to find that the package Name is "com.android.mms" and the intent is ".ui.ConversationComposer".

However this will start directly the New compose message intent, while I tried to start the view where all the SMSs are (it shall lists the SMS in my Android phone). When I trace down with "adb dumpsys window Windows", the SMS listing still uses the above intent (ui.ConversationComposer).

A Workaround for this is launching the SMS Composer and running twice

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK
```

How can I get into this view without having to Launch Composer view and pressing back twice with ADB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another work around solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools):

```
adb shell monkey -p your.app.package.name -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.android.mms 1
```