# How to trigger "Google Settings" from adb shell?

Tags: android, adb

I have a requirement where i need to launch a specific Activity of "Google Settings" app from adb shell. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help: [How to start an application using android ADB tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

You can start an activity using:

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

Answer (score 3):

You can open the Google Settings activity with this command:

```
adb shell am start -n com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.app.settings.GoogleSettingsActivity
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I want to hit "Google Settings>Ads>Reset Advertising Id" directly using adb command. can you please help me?