# How to run already installed Apk in Eclipse Through command Promt?

Tags: android, eclipse, command-prompt

My apk is already installed in Emulator. I want to launch it again through command rather than opening a menu in Emulator. How to do this?

Comment: try (emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_22)  -- (Nexus_6_API_22) is the name of your VM but use underscore for the space. You may need to change directory to the android toos folder

Answer (score 1):

Simply run

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

in your command prompt.

The question is already answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools).

Answer (score 1):

adb shell am start -n declared.manifest.package/real.activiy.package.MyActivity

See : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html for more details and options