# ADB command fails and terminates program

Tags: android, appium

The following command failed and kills the program. Am I correct in understanding that the adb shell command attempts to launch the app?

```
adb shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.test.test"
Logcat terminated with code 0, signal null
UiAutomator exited
Error: Command failed: adb ...
/bin/sh: /path/to/adb No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you able to get into the adb shell at all? Just do `adb shell`

Comment: Yes other adb shell commands can and do run.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4567928/1746118 shall help you attain launching an app using adb.

Comment: Right, I do do that. However it's just in this instance it fails. I'm curious as to why. I do not have visual logs on what happened, just these text logs.

Comment: have you set ANDROID_HOME in your path?

Comment: I did set ANDROID_HOME

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
adb shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.test.test/android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
```

Comment: @GregWringle means ,Start intent of your applications main Activity

Comment: So because it failed, that means the main Activity failed to launch? THat would be the main activity of my app?

Comment: ur not sure what is ur main activity?