# How to use the monkey command with an Android system that doesn't have physical keys?

Tags: android, monkey

If the Android system doesn't have physical keys, what are the parameters need to be included in the command?

I get the error:

```
Error : ** SYS_KEYS has no physical keys but with factor 2.0%
```

Answer (score 14):

**`--pct-syskeys 0`**

```
adb shell monkey --pct-syskeys 0 -p com.cirosantilli.android_cheat.textviewbold 1
```

Learned from: https://github.com/ARM-software/lisa/pull/408

Tested on HiKey960, Android O AOSP. Without `--pct-syskeys`, it does not open the app.

Comment: Thanks a lot. An ADB command started failing for me out of the blue, and only by pure chance i got to your answer. It did the trick.