# How to launch the previous screen app activity to my emulator?

Tags: android, shell, adb

While on a certain window of the android Settings I run the command in terminal

> adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep 'mCurrentFocus'

and I was able to get the result

> mCurrentFocus=Window{f167e7a u0
>   com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$NetworkDashboardActivity}

Now, how am I able to launch the ***mCurrentFocus*** using an ADB command on my emulator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4567904/1778421

Answer (score 0):

dumpsys window windows grep -e 'mCurrentFocus'