# Why am start -n [activity] causing error?

Tags: android

I want to access the activity named `com.isi.testapp.Welcome` which I found in the `androidmanifest.xml` file in the Activity tag with attribute **exported=True**

Now I got a shell with `adb shell`, and when I try to access it with this command `am start -n com.isi.testapp.Welcome` I got this error:-

```
usage: am [subcommand] [options]
usage: am start [-D] [-W] [-P <FILE>] [--start-profiler <FILE>]
               [--sampling INTERVAL] [-R COUNT] [-S] [--opengl-trace]
               [--user <USER_ID> | current] <INTENT>
am start: start an Activity.  Options are:
    -D: enable debugging
    -W: wait for launch to complete
    --start-profiler <FILE>: start profiler and send results to <FILE>
    --sampling INTERVAL: use sample profiling with INTERVAL microseconds
        between samples (use with --start-profiler)
    -P <FILE>: like above, but profiling stops when app goes idle
    -R: repeat the activity launch <COUNT> times.  Prior to each repeat,
        the top activity will be finished.
    -S: force stop the target app before starting the activity
    --opengl-trace: enable tracing of OpenGL functions
    --user <USER_ID> | current: Specify which user to run as; if not
        specified then run as the current user.
....................................
....................................
and finally 

Error: Bad component name: com.isi.testapp.Welcome
```

What can I do? I have read that you can access it with **-n** parameter but there is no parameter available for it. Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Try `adb shell am start -n com.isi.testapp/.Welcome`.

Comment: Oh yes! That's also worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start an application using android ADB tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the correct syntax.

MyPackageName is com.isi.testapp

MyActivityName is com.isi.testapp.MainActivity

```
adb shell am start -ncom.isi.testapp.test/com.isi.testapp.Welcome
```