# Launching the installed android application in device via terminal

Tags: android, adb

**What I have:**

1. I have application installed in device
2. I have a Mac system and I am using terminal
3. I am connected to device via terminal

**What I am trying to do:**

1. I am trying to launch the installed application via terminal ( I
   don't want to reinstall the app and run )
2. I need to find the app via package name and run it

**What I have tried:**

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools devrath$ ./adb shell monkey -p com.cnx.dictionary -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

**Error I am getting:**

```
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.
```

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567928/7436566

Comment: Check with explanation https://medium.com/towards-artificial-intelligence/how-to-run-an-android-application-from-command-line-e139eda62867

Answer (score 0):

To find the package, use `adb shell pm list packages`. There will more than likely be a lot of packages listed. If you know a part of the package name, you can use grep to limit your results. If you were looking for the Facebook package name, you could use `adb shell pm list packages | grep facebook` and it would only show results with facebook in it.

From there, you need you find the class to start.

1. `adb shell`
2. `dumpsys package | grep -Eo "^[[:space:]]+[0-9a-f]+[[:space:]]+com.packagename/[^[:space:]]+" | grep -oE "[^[:space:]]+$"` (make sure you change the "com.packagename" part to the name of your package.
3. Find the class you want to use from the output list. Most apps will have a class of `.SplashActivity`, `.HomeActivity`, or `.Main` but you will have to find the one for your app
4. When you have that, use `am start -n com.packagename/.Class` where your package name replaces `com.packagename` and the class you chose replaces `.Class`.

One thing to note. In step 1, we used the command `adb shell` so we are in the of the android device issuing the commands after. If you are issuing the `am start` command at the main terminal screen, you will have to add `adb shell` before `am start`.

I used the [zebra site](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/evm/Using-ADB-to-Determine-Package-Name-and-Launchable-Activity.html) a while back to get this info initially so i left it here for your reference as well.