# How can I launch an Android app on a device through Python?

Tags: python, adb

I have consulted several topics on the subject, but I didn't see any related to launching an app on a device directly using a `ppadb` command.

I managed to do this code:

```
import ppadb
import subprocess

from ppadb.client import Client as AdbClient

# Create the connect functiun

def connect():

   client = AdbClient(host='localhost', port=5037)
   devices = client.devices()
   for device in devices:
       print (device.serial)

   if len(devices) == 0:
       print('no device connected')
       quit()

   phone = devices[0]
   print (f'connected to {phone.serial}')

   return phone, client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    phone, client = connect()

    import time
    time.sleep(5)

    # How to print each app on the emulator
    list = phone.list_packages()
    for truc in list:
       print(truc)

# Launch the desired app through phone.shell using the package name
phone.shell(????????????????)
```

From there, I have access to each app package (com.package.name). I would like to launch it through a `phone.shell()` command but I can't access the correct syntax.

I can execute a tap or a keyevent and it's perfectly working, but I want to be sure my code won't be disturbed by any change in position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *[How to start an application using Android ADB tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools/4567928#4567928)*, the shell command to launch an app is

```
am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

Hence you would call

```
phone.shell("am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName")
```

A given package may have multiple activities. To find out what they are, you can use `dumpsys package` as follows:

```
def parse_activities(package, connection, retval):
    out = ""
    while True:
        data = connection.read(1024)
        if not data: break
        out += data.decode('utf-8')
    retval.clear()
    retval += [l.split()[-1] for l in out.splitlines() if package in l and "Activity" in l]
    connection.close()

activities = []
phone.shell("dumpsys package", handler=lambda c: parse_activities("com.package.name", c, activities))
print(activities)
```

Comment: the phone.shell ('am .......") isn't working unfortunately

Comment: "isn't working": what happens? Do you get an error message? What message?

Comment: The method you show require to have acces to the package.name and the ActivityName. I still don't know how to acces the ActivityName

So because my address was incomplete, no action or error happen.

Comment: Ah, I see. Its important to know which activity you want as a single app will usually have multiple. I've added a snippet to the answer that will help you list the activities belonging to a package on your phone with `ppadb`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct and easiest answer:

```
phone.shell('monkey -p com.package.name 1')
```

This method will launch the app without needing to have acces to the ActivityName

Answer (score 0):

Using [AndroidViewClient/cluebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient), you can launch the `MAIN` Activity of a package as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()[0].startActivity(package='com.example.package')
```

This connects to the device (*waiting if necessary*) and then invokes `startActivity()` just using the package name.

`startActivity()` can also receive a `component` which is used when you know the package and the activity.