# Communication with a device with usb in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, usb

I'm working on a project, where I have to send a specific command to a device and get the data that device is going to send through USB to my app developed in flutter.

Comment: check it once - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25398877/15950932