# How to start Android APK on device via ADB?

Tags: android, bash, react-native, adb

I have a simple android app .apk file create with Expo (react native) using the `expo build:android` script.

I am trying to run this on a device which is locked down by the provider so their is no access to Expo client. The only interface is via ADB.

I have successfully installed the app using the following command:

```bash
adb -s <device_id> install <package-name>.apk
```

I am then trying to start the app via the following:

```bash
adb shell am start -n host.exp.myapp
```

But I get the following error:

```bash
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad component name: host.exp.myapp
```

When I run `adb shell cmd package list packages`, I can see the `package:host.exp.myapp` listed and I am sure it's following naming conventions with lowercase and no special characters.

How can I start my app via ADB?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools

Answer (score 1):

Use the command

```
adb shell monkey -p com.package.name  -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

It starts the activity as if it was launched using the launcher. Replace com.package.name with desired package name in the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you only know the package name and not the Activity you can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which resolves it.

For example, if you only knows the Chrome package name `com.android.chrome` you can run

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient


device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
device.startActivity(package='com.android.chrome')
```

and it is resolved to the main Activity and then started.

If you want to do it from `adb` without using `python` you can take a look at the source [here](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py#L787).